# Extension of Euclidean Domain in which irreducibles have minimal norm

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For the ring of polynomials $F[x]$ over a field $F$, there exists a larger ring $\bar{F}[x]$, the ring of polynomials over the closure of $F$, in which irreducibles are linear polynomials -- that is, polynomials of minimal non-zero degree.

I'm wondering if this situation generalises to any Euclidean Domain $R$. Specifically, if $R$ is a Euclidean Domain with norm $M$, does there exist a Euclidean Domain $S$ with norm $N$ containing $R$ such that $N$ restricted to $R$ is $M$ and the irreducibles in $S$ have minimal non-zero norm?

(In the above example we had $R = F[x]$, $S = \bar{F}[x]$, and $M = N = $degree of polynomials.)

If $R$ is a field, the problem is trivial: take $S = R$. Otherwise, we could choose $S$ to be the field of fractions of $R$, but that involves eliminating the existence of irreducibles. Can we do better, or is the field of fractions the "minimal" choice for $S$ in some sense?

Comment: Did you figure out whether this was the case for the integers, and whether it might work to look at something like $R[x,y]/(xy - a)$? (I assume you are the one I talked to this about on IRC yesterday).

Comment: Hey, yeah I am. No I haven't made much progress on the specific case $R = \mathbb{Z}$. I still like your idea of taking that quotient though.